# Simple way to show to the user that he pressed a button by changing the background color?

Tags: ios, swift, object, uibutton

I would like, when the user presses a button, give him a feedback that he pressed the button such as a quick animated change of background color (lighter color than the one for the button's background for example).

We can use the `shows touch on highlight` from the Interface builder but it doesn't really do what I'm looking for.

On my table view I was doing this by calling `tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)` in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

Is there a similar simple way to do it or do I have to change the background color of the button through `button.layer.backgroundColor` with an animation?

Comment: I just saw that what I'm looking for might be done by using images. But I'm just surprised there is not something simple when you don't need images like me when you have button with just one simple color

Comment: If you use UIButtonTypeSystem, you can control the tint color of the button.

Comment: But the tint if only for the font it looks like, isn't it?

Comment: The tint is for the image, or font yes. I have posted a solution for background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing my comment — when you initialize your button make sure its type is `UIButtonTypeSystem`.

Then, you could change the button’s background color with the help of this class method you could add to `UIImage` category:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {    
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0, 1.0);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Then, do this to your button:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]]
                  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

#### Swift 3:

```
extension UIImage {
    public class func imageFromColor(_ color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context.fill(rect)
        }
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but I'm just surprise there is not something easier than having to build a method for something that common. By the way, do you know the alpha value of the backgroundImage when using highlighted state?

Comment: I don't know the exact value, however you could try and debug it by implementing this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8702247/3360360 (also you could later use it in your code to control the alpha for your button). Just print the alpha value in -     if(self.highlighted) {
        NSLog(@"Alpha value: %f", self.alpha);
    }